# Reputation change because of question deletion?

Tags: discussion

For example, I have an answer which is accepted by someone's question (i.e. reputation +15). Will this reputation be removed if the question is deleted by the user?

Comment: Yes. But only if it's deleted before 60 days of age.

Comment: However users can only delete questions which don't have upvoted answers (exceptions for mods and voting to delete not withstanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the circumstances.

First off, there are rules on when an author can even delete their own question:

1. They can't delete the question if there is an upvoted answer.
2. They can't delete the question if there are multiple answers, regardless of upvotes.

However, if a question is closed, it *can* be deleted by higher-rep users or moderators. This set of rules *only* applies to the author of the question.

---

Then there are also rules on whether you keep reputation:

1. The post had to be visible on the site for at least 60 days before being deleted.
2. The post has to have a score of at least 3 when it is deleted (the accepted checkmark does not affect the score).

If your post matches both of those rules at the time it gets deleted, you will keep the reputation earned on that post. Otherwise, the reputation earned will be reversed.